# Include upper bound in range()

Tags: python

How can I include the upper bound in range() function? I can't add by 1 because my for-loop looks like:

```
for x in range(1,math.floor(math.sqrt(x))):
    y = math.sqrt(n - x * x)
```

But as I understand it will actually be `1 < x < M` where I need `1 < x <= M` Adding 1 will completely change the result. 
I am trying to rewrite my old program from C# to Python. That's how it looked in C#:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= Math.Floor(Math.Sqrt(n)); x++)
    double y = Math.Sqrt(n - x * x);
```

Comment: Neither.  `range` gives you `1 <= x < M`.

Comment: What about `math.ceil`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add one to the second argument of your range function:

`range(1,math.floor(math.sqrt(x))+1)`

You could also use this:

`range(math.floor(math.sqrt(x)))`

and then add one inside your loop.  The former will be faster, however.

As an additional note, unless you're working with Python 3, you should be using xrange instead of range, for idiom/efficiency.  More idiomatically, you could also call `int` instead of `math.floor`.

Comment: Try the truth value of (1 in range(math.floor(math.sqrt(1))) or (2 in range(math.floor(math.sqrt(2))) it will return false in both cases. 1 and 2 are not considered as parts of these ranges

Answer (score 4):

Why exactly can't you simply add one to the upper bound of your `range` call?

Also, it seems like you want to refer to `n` in your first line, i.e.:

```
for x in range(1,math.floor(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
```

...assuming you want to have the same behavior as your C# snippet.